# How to autowired third part bean to my @Controller bean

Tags: xml, spring, annotations

I want to replace xml configuration  of my spring application for annotation style.

I have such @Controller:

```
@Controller

@RequestMapping("/events")

public class EventController extends AbstractController{
    @Autowired
    EventService eventService;


    Jaxb2Marshaller refMarsh;

    /// 
}
```

before i had such xml configuration:

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>com.epam.hhsystem.model.candidate.Candidate</value>
                <value>com.epam.hhsystem.model.vacancy.Vacancy</value>
                <value>com.epam.hhsystem.model.event.Event</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="eventController" class="com.epam.hhsystem.ws.controller.EventController">
        <property name="jaxb2Mashaller" ref="refMarsh" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I replace thirst bean on annotation style:

```
@Configuration
public class ContextConfiguration {



    @Bean(name = "refMarsh")
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        jaxb2Marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Event.class);
        jaxb2Marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Candidate.class);
        jaxb2Marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Vacancy.class);
        return jaxb2Marshaller;
    }
}
```

how to replace second bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you want this:

```
    @Bean(name = "eventController")
    public EventController getEventController(@Qualifier("refMarsh") Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        EventController controller = new  EventController();
        controller.setJaxb2Mashaller(marshaller);
        return controller;
    }
```

Comment: may I don't understand something. i have NPE.   it is my more detailed code:   public abstract class AbstractController {
 protected Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Mashaller;
 
 public void setJaxb2Mashaller(Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Mashaller) {
  this.jaxb2Mashaller = jaxb2Mashaller;
 
///...
 }

Comment: I think that, when I create EventController in configuration - it is another EventController, than spring create when it detect @Controller public class EventController...

Comment: Please provide full stacktrace and code. You can post it [here](https://gist.github.com/) for example.

Comment: If you declare separate bean in configuration (with `@Bean`) and as separate class (with `@Controller`) then it will be two objects in context probably. So I can't understand why you need it in Configuration class...

Comment: I answer for last comment:

Comment: I have such problem: I want to inject third part bean(Jaxb2Marshaller) to my controller(EventController).In controller's methods uses Jaxb2Marshaller. And this controller automatic use this bean when I do @ResponseBody myObject and in out of webService is xml view of myObject. Do you want to offer another way?  In first message I write working xml configuartion. I want get annotation equivalent.

Comment: I want alone EventController in context and alone Jaxb2Marshaller!

Comment: About stackTrace: NPE returns in controller's method, where I use Jaxb2Marshaller object. this object is null. NPE returns when the request is handle.

Comment: So just leave your `ContextConfiguration` as it is and add `@Autowired` in `EventController` for `refMarsh` field

Answer (score 0):

The point is how are you configuring the web configuration are you using "WebApplicationInitializer" or web.xml with listener, then in the configuration you can extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter or use @EnableWebMvc, please check these YT video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pV351E_stM

Edit 2:
ok did you added @ComponentScan and add package of your controller ? as in video you have to use @ComponentScan

Comment: this video is interesting. But there are nobody  to autowire third part bean to @Controller

Comment: I add @EnableWebMvc to ContextConfiguration class, but it has not brought changes

Comment: I have NPE for jaxbMarshaller